# Change type of Data within the condition

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the variable `vacationsPerWorkedDays` of type `double` to show the number of vacations, right now if the year is before the current year it shows fixed at 0.

```
public EmployeeDashboardDto getEmployeeDashboardYearDto(Integer year, Integer employeeId) throws QOException {  
    double vacationsPerWorkedDays = 0;
    if (fromDate.isBefore(dateAct)) {
        vacationsPerWorkedDays = 0;
    }
return employeeDashboardDto;
}
```

I need that if it is in previous years it shows `null` or `-`, but without changing the data type nor the name of the variable since it is used to collect it from the `front` because it affects other conditions.
Is there a way to do it or is it possible to change the datatype only within that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is while showing write a condition to check for valid value

```
 //before returning it to frontend/UI, send it as string
 return vacationsPerWorkedDays > 0 ? ""+ vacationsPerWorkedDays : "-"
```

and use above `String` to display

Comment: But then the new variable would be toDisplay?

Comment: you can check all the conditions using existing double and just before displaying use above condition

Comment: What I need is to show ``null`` or ``-`` but without changing the name of the variables, because it is sent to the front with that name

Comment: while returning return String using above condition, actually no need to assign it to string if confusing, updated my answer check

Comment: It does not allow to return a ``String`` because the method points to a ``Dto`` so it could only be changed the value of the variable (I put it in the code)

Comment: then you need to add a string inside DTO for display purposes or need to convert double to String at consuming end.

Answer (score 0):

```
           Date date  = new Date();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 0, 0);
        cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );
      
     Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date);
       if(cal1.before(date)){
           
           return null;
           
       }else{
// your code 
}
```